# SASS Mixin not producing the expected result

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm using SASS for a project for the first time and I love it.  I never want to write plain CSS ever again.  I am however a little confused by the following scenario and hopefully I am missing something really obvious.

First, I had the below SCSS (CSS output included):

```
// SCSS
.pos-button {
    @include linear-gradient($color-secondary-green, !important);
    @include text-shadow(lighten($color-secondary-green, 10%), !important);
    &:active {
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 2px darken($color-secondary-green, 20%) !important;
    }
    &:hover {
        @include linear-gradient(darken($color-secondary-green, 10%), !important);
        @include text-shadow($color-secondary-green);
    }
}

// CSS OUTPUT    
.pos-button {
  background: #99c965 !important;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  background: linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #99c965 !important; }
  .pos-button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px #4c6e27 !important; }
  .pos-button:hover {
    background: #80ba41 !important;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#80ba41, #4c6e27) !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#80ba41, #4c6e27) !important;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#80ba41, #4c6e27) !important;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#80ba41, #4c6e27) !important;
    background: linear-gradient(#80ba41, #4c6e27) !important;
    text-shadow: 0 1px #80ba41; }
```

Now, the problem.  I wanted to refactor the above into a mixin, but the `:hover` property isn't appearing in the CSS output:

```
// SCSS
.pos-button {
    @include color-buttons($color-secondary-green);
}

@mixin color-buttons($color) {
    @include linear-gradient($color, !important);
    @include text-shadow(lighten($color, 10%), !important);
    &:active {
        box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px 2px darken($color, 20%) !important;
    }
    &:hover {
        @include linear-gradient(darken($color, 10%), !important);
        @include text-shadow($color);
    }
}


// CSS OUTPUT
.pos-button {
  background: #99c965 !important;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  background: linear-gradient(#99c965, #669434) !important;
  text-shadow: 0 1px #99c965 !important; }
  .pos-button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 2px #4c6e27 !important; }
```

Any ideas what the problem is, or if I am hitting a limitation in SASS?  I could split the `:active` and `:hover` properties into their own mixins but  I'd really like to get this into a single one as I'm trying to keep this project as DRY as possible.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Mixins:

```
@mixin text-shadow($color, $important : null) {
    text-shadow:0 1px $color $important;
}

@mixin linear-gradient($color, $important : null) {
    $from:lighten($color, 10%);
    $to:darken($color, 10%);
    background: $from $important; // Old browsers
    background: -moz-linear-gradient($from, $to) $important; // FF3.6+
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient($from, $to) $important; // Chrome10+,Safari5.1+
    background: -o-linear-gradient($from, $to) $important; // Opera 11.10+
    background: -ms-linear-gradient($from, $to) $important; // IE10+
    background: linear-gradient($from, $to) $important; // W3C
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code of `linear-gradient` and `text-shadow` mixins?

Comment: put the complete output, not just `...` output.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov Mixins added

Comment: @sevenseacat Full output added

Comment: what's after the code you output? there's no reason why the `&:active` stuff shouldn't be output straight after.

Comment: Have you seen [Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/)?  On top of the prefixed mixins, there's other functionality that comes in handy.

Comment: @cimmanon I have seen Compass, but it was difficult enough to convince my dev lead that I should be using SASS, and from what I have read it's not easy getting Compass to play nice with Visual Studio. I'll definitely come back to compass in the future though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me: http://sassmeister.com/gist/5458986 So it must be a problem with your code structure.

I've noticed that you're calling a mixin prior to declaring it. This should've raised an error unless you have the mixin defined earlier and you're trying to redefine it. Did you originally define it without the `&:hover` part?

Please double check you're not shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Well, after taking the morning off I came back to my code and discovered a duplicate of my `color-buttons` mixin WITHOUT the `:hover` property present.  I can only imagine I did that late at night at the height of my frustration. Funny how stupid mistakes can make me feel like a total moron...  In my code, All mixins are declared ahead of any CSS rules; that was just (another) mistake when pasting into the question.